# How can I find object by an attribute other than id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I need to find multiple models in my db by a unique identifier that is not the id. Is there a way to do this in rails? Basically, I'm looking for the analog of:

```
Foo.find([1,2,3])
```

for the by_attribute helpers:

```
Foo.find_by_name(['me','you','him'])
```

The issue I'm having now is that the `find_by_name` helper is appending `LIMIT 1` to the query it creates so I'm just getting one object back rather than an array of all of the objects I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using rails 3.x:

```
Foo.find_all_by_name(['me','you','him']);
```

Or using rails 4.x

```
Foo.where(name: ['me','you','him'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd tried `find_all_by_...` but this definitely works.

Comment: If you need to upgrade to rails 4.x, see this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), dynamic methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, I figured this out as soon as I'd written up the question for Stack Overflow :)

`where` supports a list of values and will return all objects that match. So, to find all `Foos` by name:

```
Foo.where(name: ['me','you','him'])
```